# How does indexOf() know how to get the index in the ArrayList of the object passed into it?

Tags: java

How does `indexOf()` know how to get the index in the `ArrayList` of the object passed into `IndexOf()`? Like, if it was a `String`, then I get it, a string can be compared, but how does it know to identify a specific object in the `ArrayList`? Does this have something to do with getting the objects `hashCode()`?

```
public class QuoteService {

    public static List<Quote> quotes = new ArrayList<Quote>();

    public Quote addQuote(Integer id, String author, String message) throws Exception {
        //Check for already exists
        int index = quotes.indexOf(new Quote(id));
        if (index != -1) throw new Exception("Quote Record already exists");
        Quote q = new Quote(id, author, message);
        quotes.add(q);
            return q;
        }
}
```

Code taken from [here](http://rominirani.com/2014/01/10/google-cloud-endpoints-tutorial-part-1/).

Comment: No, it depends entirely on the object's `equals` implementation.

Comment: Any two objects can be compared using `equals()`. However your example looks like a typical example of a misuse of the `equals()` method.

Comment: ah! that makes sense looking at the Quotes object's equals implementation.